# GGplot - Inputting a list of data frames

Tags: r, list, ggplot2

I have a list df_list = (df1,df2,df3) of data frames, all of the same dimension but different column names.
I am calling ggplot inside a for loop:

```
for(i in 1:3){
p = ggplot(df_list[[i]], aes(x=df_list[[i]][1], y=df_list[[i]][3], fill=df_list[[i]][2])) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity', position='dodge')
}
```

However, R doesn't allow me to do this: I have to actually use the variable names, which means I can't use the loop. Any solutions?

Here is example data:

```
df1<-data.frame(order=c(1:3,4:6), gender=c('f','f','f','m','m','m'), count= c(10,20,30,20,25,30))
 
 df2<-data.frame(order11=c(2:4,2:4), gender11=c('f','f','f','m','m','m'), count= c(11,21,30,21,25,30))
 
 df3<-data.frame(order22=c(1:3,4:6), gender22=c('f','f','f','m','m','m'), count= c(10,20,31,21,25,30))
 >  df1
  order gender count
1     1      f    10
2     2      f    20
3     3      f    30
4     4      m    20
5     5      m    25
6     6      m    30
>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may have different column names in your data frames, but the roles of the columns seem to be defined by their index in the data frame.  For example, you want the first column in thr data frame to define x values in the plot and so on.  This means you can use `names()` and `aes_string()` to get what you want.

First define some test data, as you haven't given us any.

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- tibble(x1=rnorm(10), y1=rnorm(10), z1=rep(c("A", "B"), each=5))
df2 <- tibble(x2=rnorm(10), y2=rnorm(10), z2=rep(c("A", "B"), each=5))
df3 <- tibble(x3=rnorm(10), y3=rnorm(10), z3=rep(c("A", "B"), each=5))
dfList <- list(df1, df2, df3)
```

Now solve the problem

```
lapply(
  dfList,
  function(df) {
    names <- names(df)
    df %>% ggplot(aes_string(x=names[1], y=names[2], colour=names[3])) + geom_point()
  }
)
```

Giving

[image]
[image]
[image]

I've used `geom_point()` and `colour` rather than `geom_bar()` and `fill` but the same principle will apply.

Comment: I've added example data now. I am going to try this, but not sure it will work for the bar plots I'm working on.

Comment: Well, then you'd better read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) about how to create a MWE, show your desired output, and hope that someone else with better telepathic abilities than me will help you.

Comment: Thank you, this has saved a lot of labour!

Answer (score 2):

Same logic but a different approach :

```
library(tidyverse)

df_list = lst(df1,df2,df3) #This is not a typo!!

imap(df_list, ~{
  col <- names(.x)
  ggplot(.x, aes(x=.data[[col[1]]], y=.data[[col[3]]], fill=.data[[col[2]]])) + 
    geom_col(position='dodge') + 
    ggtitle(paste0('Plot for ', .y))
}) -> plot_list
```

`plot_list[[1]]`

[image]

`plot_list[[2]]`

[image]